Tracking mask is not working with Blender's compositor
I have tracked an object in Blender with a marker in some footage, then created a mask for that object and parented the mask to the marker. This works great in the Movie Clip Editor: the marker follows the object, and the mask moves with the marker.
When I add the movie clip and the mask to the Compositor and connect them to an Alpha Over node, then I can see the masked area on the object. However, the mask does not follow the marker anymore, as if it was not parented to it. How can this be done?

The mask needs to be aligned with the track position in the compositor.
This is done by using the Track Position node, where you need to select the footage, the tracked object, and the track. The Position must be set to "Relative Start". Then you connect the node's X and Y output to the corresponding input of the Translate node.
The Mask node's Mask output needs to be connected to the Translate node's Image input.
Now you can use the Image output of the Translate node as the Fac input of the Alpha Over node.
